# Errors trying to append specific number of floats from user input

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, if-statement, input

```
x={}
continueQ=input("would you like to continue?"))
if (continueQ=="yes"):
    #if there is less than 4

    if x<4:        

        variable=float(input("Input a float to append to the array:") 
        x.append(variable)
        print(x)


    else:           
        print(x)
else:
    print("Goodbye!")
```

There are a few errors in this code, could someone help me how to create an **if statement** to **check** if there are **minimum** than **4 values** inside an **array** .
Also how to **append** to an **array** from an **input**.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: You can calculate the length of a list (arrays are called lists in Python).

`len(x)`

Comment: You created a dictionary, not an array. What i would suggest is `x=[]` which makes x a list. To check how many elements there are in the list you can use `len(x)`.

Comment: you created a dictionary, not a list. An empty list is created by `x = []`

Comment: In addition to other comments, I'd invite to read the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) that happens to answer both of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list with `x = []`, Use `len(x)` to get the length of list, use `while` loop with condition if x<4

```
x=[]
continueQ=input("would you like to continue?")
if (continueQ=="yes"):
    #if there is less than 4

    while len(x)<4:

        variable=float(input("Input a float to append to the array:"))
        x.append(variable)
        print(x)


    else:
        print(x)
else:
    print("Goodbye!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'll want to do is change that `x={}` to an `x=[]`. What you've done is create a dictionary rather than an array, and consequently will run into an assortment of issues as you're dealing with the wrong data structure.

Once you've done that, we can move on to how to check if there are less than 4 values inside an array. In Python, arrays carry a length attribute, which can be accessed by writing `len(arrayName)`, or in your case, `len(x)`. For example, if your array `x` contained the following values: `[1,2,3]`, then `len(x)` would return `3`, seems simple enough.

Now to check that the length is less than 4, you need to replace your `if x<4:` with `if len(x)<4:`.

You already have the correct code to append to your array, it likely wasn't working before because you created a dictionary instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code. Here's a working version:

```
x = []

continueQ = input('Would you like to continue?')

if continueQ.lower() == 'yes':

    while len(x) < 4:

        variable=float(input('Input a float to append to the array:'))
        x.append(variable)
        print(x)

print("Goodbye!")
```

**Explanation**

1. `[]` represents an empty list, while `{}` is use for an empty set.
2. Make sure your bracketing is consistent; all open brackets must be closed.
3. Use `len(x)` to find the number of entries in a list `x`.
4. Use a `while` loop to repeat logic until a criterion is satisfied.